# React application import repeat

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am wondering for React applications, does the `import` on a component happen during run time? When developing React applications, it is common to have all the React code bundled in to one file, this made me wonder whether or not the importing of a component happens every time the component mounts.

For example;

```
import About from '../components/About';

class About extends React.component {
   render() {...}
}
```

When the code is all bundled and during production or development run time, does the `About` component get imported only once or every time the component mounts?

Answer (score 1):

ES6 module imports happen at build time, so the component will get bundled with other code before it's even run. Imports are handled before code is evaluated and cannot be dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

`import` evaluation is specified to happen only once in the *ECMA-262, 9th edition, June 2018 ECMAScript® 2018 Language Specification* - specificially in [*15.2.1.16.5.1 InnerModuleEvaluation*](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-innermoduleevaluation) and in [*15.2.1.17 Runtime Semantics: HostResolveImportedModule*](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-hostresolveimportedmodule):

> - This operation must be idempotent if it completes normally. Each time it is called with a specific `referencingModule`, `specifier` pair as arguments it must return the same Module Record instance.
>     Multiple different `referencingModule`, `specifier` pairs may map to the same Module Record instance. The actual mapping semantic is implementation-defined but typically a normalization process is applied to `specifier` as part of the mapping process. A typical normalization process would include actions such as alphabetic case folding and expansion of relative and abbreviated path specifiers.

~ [*15.2.1.17*](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-hostresolveimportedmodule)

> [2](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-hostresolveimportedmodule). If module.[[Status]] is "evaluated", then
>     a. If module.[[EvaluationError]] is undefined, return index.
>     b. Otherwise return module.[[EvaluationError]].
>   [3]. If module.[[Status]] is "evaluating", return index.
>   [4]. Assert: module.[[Status]] is "instantiated".
>   [5]. Set module.[[Status]] to "evaluating".
>   ...snip ...
>   [12]. Assert: module occurs exactly once in stack.

~ [*15.2.1.16.5.1*](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-innermoduleevaluation)

If you are transpiling, then the transpiler (e. g. webpack) is responsible for ensuring that your bundle conforms to the expected "implementation-defined" semantics (in most cases, how Node / a browser would de-duplicate requests for `specifier`).

Comment: If it only happens once, do you know how CSS to JS modules get loaded? I had thought that the SASS files being imported in the React components files would be imported everytime that particular component is mounted, preventing CSS styles from ever conflicting.

Comment: How they are loaded is dependent on your bundler.  There is no finalized concept (yet) of non-JS modules from the specification's perspective.  There are several ways that CSS-to-JS modules *may* be loaded ranging from "once, same as JS modules" for the webpack `style-loader` approach through "mounted and unmounted as the components are" for certain Higher-Order Component approaches used by things like emotion / styled-components, to "never, the CSS is in a separate file that you're responsible for loading" like when using webpack's `css-loader` with the `mini-css-extract` plugin.